# What is wrong with my RABL file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, rabl

Rabl is not generating the main object but it is generating it for its children nodes.

I have a Rails-Angularjs project. I want to use RABL to generate the json file. I have read the RABL's documentation and created the Rabl file for the action show, which is not working properly, as explained:

```
object @ticket => :ticket do
  attributes :id, :name, :subname, :description, :width, :height, :qty, :single, :double, :project_id, :material_id, :equipment_id, :location_id, :created_at, :updated_at
end

child :project do
  attributes :name, :nickname, :project_number
end 

child :job_state do 
  attributes :color, :name 
end

child :location do
  attributes :name
end

child :local_equipment do
  attributes :name
end

child :local_material do
  attributes :name
end
```

`IF I` remove 'do' and 'end' on the object @ticket, It throws the error: `'wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)'.`

If I leave them, it doesn't show any ticket's field name. As shown below:

```
{"ticket":{"project":{"name":"Information Security Conference 2017","nickname":"infosecon17","project_number":1000},"job_state":{"color":"red","name":"printed"},"location":{"name":"Grand prairie graphics"},"local_equipment":null,"local_material":null}}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the issue is not with your Angular, from rails side, this is the structure that works for me. Check that your Tickets#show file is here and named: app\views\tickets\show.json.rabl and contains only

```
object @ticket
attributes :id, :name, :subname, :description, :width, :height, :qty, :single, :double, :project_id, :material_id, :equipment_id, :location_id, :created_at, :updated_at
```

for the children you would have separate files like this:
app\views\tickets\projects.json.rabl which will contain

```
collection @projects
extends "projects/show"
```

but also confirm that attributes match your schema anyway.

Comment: @user3538384, I could see you accepted this answer but the answer mentioned different possibilities (your angular, the attributes or the structure of the rabl files). It would be useful if you can say which one fixed your problem. That way, others having similar problem can learn. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you're on the right track. I would make one small change. You don't need to wrap the `@ticket` attributes in a block. You can just specify `object @ticket` and go from there.

```
object @ticket
attributes :id, :name, :subname, :description, :width, :height, :qty, :single, :double, :project_id, :material_id, :equipment_id, :location_id, :created_at, :updated_at

child :project do
  attributes :name, :nickname, :project_number
end 

child :job_state do 
  attributes :color, :name 
end

child :location do
  attributes :name
end

child :local_equipment do
  attributes :name
end

child :local_material do
  attributes :name
end
```

Comment: Thank you Derek Hopper for your quick response. I really appreciate it. but as I explained, If I do what you said. It throws an error: ArgumentError in Tickets#show . wrong number of arguments (1 for 0). I understand you are correct and I tried it before. A have Rails 4.2.6 installed, in case it is important.

Comment: For the `@ticket` attributes, have you tried only specifying the id like this: `attributes :id`. Maybe there's an attribute in the list which is requiring an argument.